# expo build FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures

Tags: android, expo, build.gradle

THIS IS A MANAGED EXPO PROECT

Running 'gradlew :app:assembleDebug' in /home/expo/workingdir/build/android

Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.0.1-all.zip

> Configure project :app
> ℹ️  Applying gradle plugin 'expo-dev-launcher-gradle-plugin' (expo-dev-launcher@2.4.10)
> ℹ️  Applying gradle plugin 'expo-updates-gradle-plugin' (expo-updates@0.18.12)

[stderr] FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

[stderr] 1: Task failed with an exception.

### [stderr]

[stderr] * Where:

[stderr] Build file '/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-error-recovery/android/build.gradle' line: 40

[stderr] * What went wrong:

[stderr] A problem occurred evaluating project ':expo-error-recovery'.

[stderr] > Could not set unknown property 'classifier' for task ':expo-error-recovery:androidSourcesJar' of type org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar.

[stderr] * Try:

[stderr] > Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.

[stderr] > Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

[stderr] > Run with --scan to get full insights.

## [stderr]

[stderr] 2: Task failed with an exception.

[stderr] -----------

[stderr] * What went wrong:

[stderr] A problem occurred configuring project ':expo'.

[stderr] > compileSdkVersion is not specified. Please add it to build.gradle

[stderr]

- Try:

[stderr] > Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.

[stderr] > Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

[stderr] > Run with --scan to get full insights.

[stderr]==============================================================================

[stderr] * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

[stderr] BUILD FAILED in 2m 12s

15 actionable tasks: 15 executed

Error: Gradle build failed with unknown error. See logs for the "Run gradlew" phase for more information.

I tried changing my sdk PATH.
ALso changed Classifier to archiveClassifier. IDK if it even recognize it.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this from divonelnc.

https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/23023

After pulling my project from git, I searched expo-error-recovery and deleted all the files for it before running npm i.
Then I ran npx eas build --profile development --platform android.
Error gone. build complete.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).